# Find the number of those $[a]\in \langle[5]\rangle$ such that $\gcd(a,6)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Consider the finite cyclic group $\mathbb Z_{150}$.
>   Consider the cyclic subgroup generated by $[5]$ which is 
>   $\langle[5]\rangle=\{[5],[10],[15],\ldots ,[145],[0]\}$  .
>   Find the number of those $[a]\in \langle[5]\rangle$  such that $\gcd(a,6)=1$

**My try**

I know $150=2.3.5^2$.
Now if I write in explicitly in hand, I found set of all $a$ such that $\gcd(a,6)=1$ to be the following set:

$\{5,25,35,55,65,85,95,115,125,145\}$.

Is there any explicit formula to calculate the above?

I will be grateful for some help.

In general my question is :

> If $n=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\alpha_i}$ what will be the number of those $[a]\in \langle p_k\rangle $ such that $\gcd(a,p_1p_2\cdots p_{k-1})=1$?

Answer (score 1):

$[a]\in \langle[5]\rangle$ if and only if  $a=5n$ for some integer, $1 \le n \le 29$.

$(a,6)=1 \iff (5n, 6)=1 \iff 2 \not \mid n \vee 3 \not \mid n$

There are $14$ multiples of $2$ between $1$ and $29$.

There are $9$ multiples of $3$ between $1$ and $29$.

There are $4$ multiples of $6$ (both $2$ and $3$) between $1$ and $29$.

Hence there are $14 + 9 - 4 = 19$ multiples of $2$ or $3$ between $1$ and $29$.

Hence there are $10 = 29-19$ elements $[a]\in \langle[5]\rangle$ such that $(a,6) = 1$.

Comment: How will I manage if there are more factors in $n$ , suppose $n=2\times 3\times 7\times 11\times 5^2$ , Is there any formula for this

Comment: The formula is $\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor + \lfloor \frac n3 \rfloor - \lfloor \frac n6 \rfloor$

Comment: the formula holds here, i was asking what happens if there are more prime factors

Comment: Suppose $n=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\alpha_i}$ is there any way to do it

Comment: I have added more info for my question. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

The congruence system: $\,a\equiv 0\pmod{\!5},\,\ \overbrace{a\equiv \color{#0a0}{-1},\,\color{#90f}{1}\pmod{\!6}}^{\textstyle \gcd(a,6)=1}\ $ has $\,\color{#c00}2\,$ solutions $\,\color{#0a0}5,\color{#90f}{25}\pmod{\! 30}\,$ by CRT, which lift to $\,\color{#c00}2(150/30) = 10\,$ solutions $\!\bmod 150,\,$ viz $\,\{\color{#0a0}5,\color{#90f}{25}\}+30k,\ k = 0,\ldots, 4,\,$ since $\,5n\bmod 150 = 5(n\bmod 30)\,$ by the [$\!\bmod\!$ Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242).